# Differential equations: tricky integral involving exponential and trigonometric functions

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

While doing differential equations homework the integral $$\int \exp\left(\sec^2x\right)\, 2x\cos(x) \,dx$$ popped up and I've been struggling with it for a while.

Any help with integral would be much appreciated.

Comment: It looks like it doesn't have an elementary solution. My guess is that you made some mistakes prior to getting to the integral otherwise you might have to leave your solution in this form.

Comment: @wildesbare : There is no differential equation in your question. It's a question about an integral only. So, the title is not correct and you should change it. If is in an integral derived from a problem of differential equation, the title is OK., but you have to edit the differential equation in the wording of the question.

Comment: Is there any reason for the factor $2$ to be left here?

Comment: Without $x$ the integral can be written in the form: $$\int \cos x e^{\sec^2 x} dx=\sqrt{e} \int \frac{e^{0.5 \cosh u}}{1+\cosh u} du$$ Where $$u=2 \cosh^{-1} \sec x$$ Looks somewhat like Bessel, but not quite, much more complicated. I doubt there's a closed form in terms of any known special functions

Answer (score 0):

Usually the exponent appears in derivatives of exponential function, so we take derivative of $\exp(\sec^2 x)$ and compare it with integrant to estimate the integral.

$$ e^{\sec^2 x}=e^ \frac{1}{\cos^2 x}$$

$$\left(e^ \frac{1}{\cos^2 x} \right)'=-\frac{2\sin x \cos x}{\cos^4 x}. e^ \frac{1}{\cos^2 x}$$

$$I=\int e^ \frac{1}{\cos^2 x}2 x \cos x dx =\int e^ \frac{1}{\cos^2 x}\frac{-2  \sin x \cos x}{\cos^4 x} dx \cdot \left(\frac{-x \cos^4 x}{\sin x}\right) $$

Integrating by parts we have:

$$I=\left(\frac{-x \cos^4 x}{\sin x} \right) \cdot \left(e^ \frac{1}{\cos^2 x} \right)- \int \left(\frac{-x \cos^4 x}{\sin x} \right)'.e^ \frac{1}{\cos^2 x} dx$$

you can continue integrating but I do not think it can have a closed form.

Comment: I fixed your formatting a little. While it's not required, nice looking equations would usually lead to a better reception of your posts

Comment: @Yuriy SThank you Yuriy, my Latex is not so good.